# How to Concatenate two or more TextInputs, React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, concatenation, textinput

I want to concatenate the textInputs on clicking the button.
e.g text1=2 , text2=3 , text3=9 and text4=8, the final result should be 2398.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Fetch values of every input and do string concatenation: `result = str1 + str2`.

Comment: I know dupe link is on jQuery and not on react, but it show *how to* and this logic can be integrated with React

Answer (score 0):

If you were using ES6 standards, you can use string literals

```
const txt1 = 'rt';
const txt2 = 'rete';
const concatenated = `${txt1}${txt2}`
```

you can refer the link for further learning:
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 0):

create one onChangeHandler() for textInput such as:

```
 <TextInput onChange={(text)=>(this.onChangeHandler("text1",text))}>
 <TextInput onChange={(text)=>(this.onChangeHandler("text2",text))}>
 <TextInput onChange={(text)=>(this.onChangeHandler("text3",text))}>

onChangeHandler=(name,value)=>{
    this.setState({[name]:value})
}
```

then on button click do this:

```
onButtonClick=()=>{
    let finalText =this.state.text1+this.state.text2+this.state.text3
    console.log(finalText)  //prints the concatenated text.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With `Pure JS`

```js
function concatenate(){
var concatenate = document.getElementById("input1").value + document.getElementById("input2").value + document.getElementById("input3").value

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Resultat:"+concatenate
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text" name="name1" >
<input id="input2" type="text" name="name2" >
<input id="input3" type="text" name="name3" >

<button type="button" onclick="concatenate()">concatenate</button>

<div id="result">Resultat: </div>
```